# Drupal 7: Collection of nodes field

Tags: 7, nodes

Which is the best way to attach a collection of nodes to another node?

I'm creating a meal and ingredients nodes. I want to assign multiple ingredients to a meal and I'd like to do it programatically via modules ( content types )

Which is the best way to achieve this? Can you point me to the right direction ( links, etc...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What about a taxonomy vocabulary for the ingredients list, and then just reference those taxonomy terms in your meal node?
- You could try the [Insert View](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view) module, create a view with whatever other nodes you want, and then display it at the right place in your node
- If you want something a bit more complex, you could [relate](http://drupal.org/project/relation) the meal node with the ingredient nodes, and collect them with a view, and *then* use Insert Views.

As a general note though, [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) sounds like what you want to use -- it's perfect for that collecting of different information from other nodes and displaying it.

Comment: I want the ingredients to be nodes (entities) with custom attributes not strings. Thanks though